# Form builder fields from dynamic JSON

Tags: .net, json, botframework, formflow

I want to populate a form with fields that are both manually added and dynamically added.

```
public class ModelClass
{
    [Prompt("URL?")]
            public string URL { get; set; }
            [Prompt("Name?")]
            public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Formbuilder:

```
 public IForm<ModelClass> BuildApplyform()
        {
            var builder = new FormBuilder<ModelClass>(); 
            // Parse string to json for usage in the foreach
            dynamic json = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

            builder.Message("Form builder");
            builder.Field(nameof(ModelClass.Title), active: (state) => false);
            builder.Field(nameof(ModelClass.URL), active: (state) => false);
            foreach(string param in json.Parameters)
            {
                builder.Field(param);
            }
            return builder.Build();
        }
```

The JSONstring is very dynamic and can be different every time. However, the string always contains the "d" and "parameter"childnodes.
The string could look like:

```
"{
  \n\t\"d\":  {
    \n\t\t\"parameters\":  [
      {
        \n\t\t\t\"id\":  \"url\",
        \n\t\t\t\"name\":  \"Site URL\",
        \n\t\t\t\"required\":  \"text\"
      },
       {
        \n\t\t\t\"id\":  \"title\",
        \n\t\t\t\"URL\":  \"Title\",
        \n\t\t\t\"required\":  true,
        \n\t\t\t\"example\":  \"www.stackoverflow.com\"\n\t\t
      }
    ]\n\t
  }\n
}"
```

How can I make sure that no matter what the JSON looks like, the parameters are dynamically added as field input's in the form builder?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you like to dynamically define field values and the field values are stored in a JSON file?

Comment: I'd like the field values from the JSON file (such as id:, required: and example:) to be dynamically filled in by the user. Therefore they need to dynamically added into the form via the JSON file, as every JSON file is just a bit different.

Comment: I don't think you can dynamically add fields to formflow like that.  I think you'll need to define the entire form using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow.Json  Some documentation can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow-json-schema

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That would mean I cannot use both hardcoded fields and JSON at the same time right?

Comment: I think you would need a custom version of this: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/1f144aa4a8bfc1e7fb4d4914bb95072406150a0f/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow.Json/FormBuilderJson.cs that combines a underlying form class with a .json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Impossible**

Alright, after some more research I found out it was practically impossible what I was trying to achieve.
It's not possible to dynamically add fields, and add static fields at the same time with the Bot Framework. So formbuilder is not a realistic possibility in such a case.As Eric Dahlvang mentioned: it is a possibility when you use JSON only via a JSON schema with form builder.

**How I solved this problem:**

During my search of using Form Builder I stumbled upon a solution that loops through a promptdialog. It's possible to read JSON and convert it into C# objects so you can iterate them, so why not use that?

Globally define a list of strings, or as I used "Parameter object":

```
public class Parameter
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Required { get; set; }
    public string Example { get; set; }
}
```

Then you'd have to get the JSON parameters and convert them to the C# object (Parameter). I used a global List to access the params later on. Then I prompted the first question (parameter) so the loop starts.The job contains the parsed JSON.

```
    public void SomeFunction(IDialogContext context)
{
        if (job["d"]["parameters"] != null)
                    {
                        var t = job["d"]["parameters"];
                        parameters = GetParametersFromJSON(t); // parameters is a globally defined list of <Parameter>
                    }
                    currentParameter = parameters[0];
                    PromptDialog.Text(context, ParamPrompt, "Please fill in: " + currentParameter.Title+ $", for example: {currentParameter.sampleValue}");
}



private async Task ParamPrompt(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> 
result)
{
    var answer = await result;

        index++;
        if (index < parameters.Count)
        {
            currentParameter = parameters[index];
            PromptDialog.Text(context, ParamPrompt, "Please fill in: " + currentParameter.Title + $", for example: {currentParameter.example}");
        }
       else 
       {
           // handle logic, the loop is done.
       }
    }
```